# Why did Mark Antony not report Trebonius’ plot to kill Julius Caesar?

Tags: julius-caesar

Trebonius approached Mark Antony at Narbo and asked him to join a plot to kill Caesar, I don’t understand why one of Caesar’s most loyal men, Antony, wouldn’t report the plot. Considering Trebonius was one of the main instigators, this could have saved Caesar’s life.

Why did Mark Antony not tell Caesar?

Comment: Because it probably never happened.  It seems the account of the meeting between Trebonius & Mark Antony comes from a misinterpretation/elaboration of Cicero's _Epistulae ad Familiares_ and _Philippics_ by Plutarch.  Whether this misinterpretation/elaboration deliberate or accidental is unknown, and probably unknowable.  The antipathy between Cicero and Mark Antony is well-known, and [ultimately resulted in Cicero's death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicero#Opposition_to_Mark_Antony_and_death).

Comment: @sempaiscuba Seems like an answer.